# OS detection - empty variable

Tags: javascript, php

What I'm trying to achieve is to trigger automatic file download based on user's OS. With following code I'm getting empty strings (while there should be url to the file) and page-refresh loop.

e.g.

```
Windows
var downloadTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
    window.location = 'there supposed to be url to file but its blank';
}, 500);
```

Could someone guide me what am I doing wrong?

OS detection:

```
<?php 
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

function getOS() { 

    global $user_agent;

    $os_platform  = "Unknown OS Platform";

    $os_array     = array(
                          '/windows nt 10/i'      =>  'Windows 10',
                          '/windows nt 6.3/i'     =>  'Windows 8.1',
                          '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
                          '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
                          '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
                          '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
                          '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
                          '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
                          '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
                          '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
                          '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
                          '/win95/i'              =>  'Windows 95',
                          '/win16/i'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
                          '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'Mac OS X',
                          '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
                          '/linux/i'              =>  'Linux',
                          '/ubuntu/i'             =>  'Ubuntu',
                          '/iphone/i'             =>  'iPhone',
                          '/ipod/i'               =>  'iPod',
                          '/ipad/i'               =>  'iPad',
                    );

    foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value)
        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent))
            $os_platform = $value;

    return $os_platform;
}

if( substr(getOS(), 0, 6) === 'Windows' ){
    $file = 'https://path-to-file.exe';
}
else if( substr(getOS(), 0, 2) === 'Mac'  ){
    $file = 'https://path-to-file.dmg';
}
else if( substr(getOS(), 0, 4) === 'Linux'  ){
    $file = 'https://path.air';
}
else{
}
?>
```

Automatic download trigger:

```
var downloadTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
    window.location = '<?php echo $file; ?>';
}, 500);
```

Comment: So where is `$file` initialized and returned? Your `.php` determines the OS, but then doesn't send down a URL to the client to relocate to.

Comment: I think your solution for sniffing the browser is pretty nice. Although all of those if else statements could be reduced to a nice switch statement.

Comment: OT, but: Why go through so much trouble, only to present me with a file I might not even want? I might have just come by to download the file for one system, using another ... You're over-complicating things and essentially degrading the user experience, in a situation where a simple list of links with appropriate description would do a better job. Maybe _suggest_ or highlight the most likely needed file, but keep the other options available & the whole thing the user's choice.

Comment: @CBroe For all we know, a user arrives at this page after clicking a link that says "take me to the appropriate download page for my OS".

Comment: I don't think it's related to the problem, but you should break out of the loop when you find a match.

Comment: @CBroe What he's trying to do is pretty common, most users don't care about irrelevant downloads. You can always provide a link to another page that lets you select your downloads.

Comment: Is the download trigger code in the same PHP script as the code that sets `$file`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it's the same file.

Comment: Your `substr()` calls have the wrong length for `Mac` and `Linux`, they should be `3` and `5`.

Comment: Don't call `getOS()` repeatedly. Save the result in a variable and test this. Also, then you can echo the result and see if it's working properly.

Comment: I think you should add a "dummy" value to the `else` branch and see if that's what you get in the JavaScript because it seems like your code is always winding up in the `else` and returning nothing to the client.

Comment: @Barmar _"What he's trying to do is pretty common"_ - see also: flies/sh*t :-) _"You can always provide a link to another page that lets you select your downloads"_ - as long as you don't throw the unnecessary download in my face automatically first ... (which in common browsers would already start receiving data in the background if I'm not mistaken.)

Comment: @CBroe We're venturing into [ux.se] territory. There are ways to do this reasonably, like a "Start download" button that downloads for your OS, along with a link to a page with other download links.

Comment: @Barmar sounds like what I was saying to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a little workaround which works for me. Nothing fancy, just an idea

getOS() was working fine and echoing my OS; based on options in $os_array so I've put links to my files instead of OS names and than used getOS instead of $file variable. Ugly, but at least works

Comment: This answer is really hard to understand. Show how you've rewritten the code to solve the problem.